# Objective-C - Passing Multiple Parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So up until now i would just pass any parameter i need via the buttons tag. However now i am using the tag already for something else so i need to be able to pass another string and a timer value with the tag to a void or action of some kind when you select the button.

This is my current button code for passing the buttons tag with to the action (below)

```
[mybtn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This is the void or action i am passing it to.

```
-(void)action:(UIButton*)btn{
NSLog(@"%d", [btn tag]);
}
```

So is there a way i can pass more than just the buttons tag (like a string) to the action? so i could have something like this.

```
-(void)action:(UIButton*)btn :myString{
NSLog(@"%d %@", [btn tag], myString);
}
```

**Edit:**
So now thanks to the suggestion my void looks like this

```
-(void)actionWithButton:(UIButton *)btn andString:(NSString *)myString{
NSLog(@"%d %@", [btn tag], myString);
}
```

But i still don't know how to pass the myString parameter in the @selector part of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an UILable as a subView to that Button like

```
 UILabel *lblValue = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
 lblValue.tag=2;
 lblValue.text = myString;
 [objInputButton addSubview:lblValue];
```

and you get your string in your Action method like below

```
  -(void)action:(UIButton*)btn
     {
     for(UILabel *lable in [btn subViews])
         {
              if([lable tag]==2)
                   {
                         //get your string from lable
                   }
         }
     }
```

**Edit:-**
This answer by me is posted when I am starting my career, it is bad way of passing data even though it get works done, so, it is better to follow other answer posted by me.

Comment: This look like it may be the answer i am looking for however on the for loop i am getting "No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'subViews'" **Edit** Oops i put a capital V in subviews - fixed now

Comment: @Mattigins, yep, this is a way to solve the problem. :) but the real situation is: **that** string what you added to the `UILabel` is **already** exists when you created the `UIButton`, so there is no point to add it to the `UIButton` because you can read the information out from that object where you added the string from to the `UIButton` before... but this is just a simple misunderstanding the whole MVC model.

Answer (score 1):

[this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) is a good start for you to understand how the actions will be posted to the target.

you can see the target selectors can be three different ones only:

```
- (IBAction)action;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

you cannot receive any other type of parameter because you are just a receiver, **not you will call these methods**.

I'm quite sure why you want "pass" (you would mean: receive) any string when they are called. the user interaction indicates **when** let them be called and at the moment of the calling any of these methods, you must have every data which you should have enough to response the user's request. a simple user tap won't create any extra string what you need to receive, but you would get information about the touch event.

I strongly recommend you to find a good tutorial about *how the MVC works*.

---

however you can post a simple `NSInteger` value via the `tag` property of `UIButton`, when you create the `UIButton` you can set the `tag` of it, and you can read that `tag` when one of the methods is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that like this:

```
-(void)actionWithButton:(UIButton *)button andString:(NSString *)myString{
    //code
}
```

I do suggest you read a basic introduction to objective-c (the [apple developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) is very good! Or if you would like a book, I higly recommend [Stephen Kochan's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321811909))

Comment: i think, he want answer that how to pass other parameter to `actionEvent`. This answer did not seem to want.

Comment: Ok i understand but how do i pass a string to 'myString' from the button?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the UIButton was custom, you could have an image with the text on it. Then the *titleLabel* property of the button could be used for the text.

Answer (score 0):

If Your only requirement is to retrieve some information beyond tag from the button at the time of event(touchupinside) dispatch then you can subclass UIButton and then assign whatever information you want to use with the button so that you can get it later.

Possibly you can use like below

```
-(void)action:(CustomButton*)btn{
      NSLog(@"%d %@", [btn tag], btn.value); // assuming CustomButton is a derived class of UIButton
}
```